# Garbage values in From: in the email sent from Webform

Tags: 7, emails

I find some garbage values in the from field of email sent from contact us page in webmail(as in the image From= field below in the top left in which "F" is cut-off by mistake). I've configured correctly as we do in D6.

I've also sent email from my webmail account from the same email account and it's ok.

This site is the latest version( 1 month old only).

Here I'm pasting what is seen in the image in text:

From: =?UTF-8?B?Ij0/VVRGLTg/Qj9RV1J0YVhOemFXOXVJRU52ZFhKelpYTWdTVzVrYVdFaElPQ2s=?=

This snapshot is from Thunderbird email client:

[image]

Looks like it is appearing from this(snippet from the email headers ):

........
X-Mailer: Drupal Webform (PHP/5.3.23)
From: =?UTF-8?B?Ij0/VVRGLTg/Qj9RV1J0YVhOemFXOXVJRU52ZFhKelpYTWdTVzVrYVdFaElPQ2s=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?cXVDbGplQ2tzT0NrdGVDbGgrQ2t0aURncEtvPT89CiA9P1VURi04P0I/NEtTKzQ=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?S1NnNEtXTjRLU3Y0S1NWNEtXTjRLU3c0S1N1SU9Da3JlQ2t2dUNrc09Da3BDRGc=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?cEs3Z3BZZmdwSUk9Pz0iIDxjb250YWN0dXNAYWRtaXNzaW9uY291cnNlcy5jb20=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?Pg==?=

I've Googled too but did not find any similar issue anywhere else.

**Am I missing anything?**

Comment: This looks like base-64 encoded data sent as possible spam/attack. I could be wrong though. I'd suggest putting captcha on your form.

Answer (score 1):

If you fill out the form and submit it does your message contain similar encoded data in the from field?

If not, then it's likely these are spam submissions.

Try adding [Spamicide](https://drupal.org/project/Spamicide) and/or [reCAPTCHA](https://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) to filter these out.

Comment: Hmm... it looks like the screenshot above _is_ a test...